# Taking a Timer Value From One Form to Another

Tags: c#, timer, global-variables

So I am making a small video game in c#, the scoring system is measured in seconds. When the player completes the level I want to take the Timers value and store the time on a database of other players times.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    I++;
    lblView.Text = I.ToString() + " Seconds";
}
```

this is the code for my timer.

I'm not sure how to make the I variable, i have used for the timer a global variable.Sorry if this seems vague i'm having trouble describing what I want to happen.

Comment: place it in some `static` class as a `static variable`  .and access it from every where you want ..

Comment: @usmanlqbal i tried and it hasn't worked for me :/ 
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public static class Global
    {
        public static int i = 0;
        
    }
}

Comment: could you share the code that have you written for `static` class and how you access the static variable in that .. and also explain that what error you got when  to accessing  that `static` variable.?

Comment: @usmanlqbal 
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        private SoundPlayer _soundPlayer;
        bool right, left;
        bool jump;
        int G = 30;
        int Force;
        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        private void timer2_Tick(Global sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            lblView.Text = i.ToString() + " Seconds";
        }

Comment: @usmanlqbal
The static variable in a new static class

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public static class Global
    {
        public static int i = 0;
        
    }
}

Comment: @usmanlqbal


The error i get tells me that i doesn't exist in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static Class Syntax

```
public static class Helper { public static int I = 0; }
```

Accessing the `static` variable.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Helper.I++;//here accessing static variable
    lblView.Text = Helper.I.ToString() + " Seconds";
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help I really appreciate it, got it working now :)